# How to change Password in java through access Database?

Tags: java, sql, database, passwords

I am working on a project that User can Signup  and Login. 
And If your want to change His/her password then how to change it. I need its access related query.

try {

```
                    String passcheck = Oldpass.getText();
                    String newpassword = newpass.getText();
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:patientsystem");
                    String passw   = "UPDATE Guest SET password='"+newpassword+"' WHERE password='"+passcheck+"' ";
                    s = conn.prepareStatement(passw);
                    s.setString(1,newpassword );

                    s.execute();

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password changed");

                    rs.close();
                    s.close();

                } catch (Exception es) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, es.getMessage());
                }
```

Comment: Post some code??!?! Anyway if you already did the login, you should have to follow the "same code" but change the query

Comment: try {
                        
                        String passcheck = Oldpass.getText();
                        String newpassword = newpass.getText();
                       
                        String passw   = "UPDATE Guest SET password='"+newpassword+"' WHERE password='"+passcheck+"' ";
                        s = conn.prepareStatement(passw);
                        s.setString(1,newpassword );
                        
                        s.execute();

Comment: But this query is not working , @Alist3r How I can use that login code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have to do 2 different queries:

1) Check the old password with a SELECT

2) Then if the old_password_input fit with the password in the db save the ID of the user.

3) Update the password where idFound = id_in_the_db

```
SELECT guest.id
FROM guest
where guest.password = checkpassword AND guest.username = username
```

You have to check the username too. The only password its not enough.
Now you have the guest.id

So you can do this:

```
UPDATE Guest SET password = newpassword' WHERE guest.id = idFound
```